# When $\int_{[a, b]} f(x) d\mu_1(x)\ge \int_{[a, b]} f(x) d\mu_2(x)?$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, measure-theory

I am studying for the measure theory exam and I am practicing with some exercises the lecturer has left us as homework.
I am done with most of them, but I am in stuck with the following one.

Let $a, b\ge 0$, $\mu_1, \mu_2$ be two positive and finite measures and let $f:[a, b]\to\mathbb R$ be a $\mu_1$-measurable and $\mu_2$-measurable positive function.
Which condition/conditions on $\mu_1, \mu_2$ guarantee that
$$\int_{[a, b]} f(x) d\mu_1(x)\ge \int_{[a, b]} f(x) d\mu_2(x)?$$

Clearly this is true if $\mu_1=\mu_2$ (one gets exactly the equality). It should be true also if $\mu_2$ is a Dirac delta $\delta(A)$, where $A$ is a subset of $\mathbb R$ which does not contain $[a, b]$.

I’m stuck and I can not find any other example (the lecturer suggested to think about a condition which involves both $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ and $[a, b]$). I am in stuck.
Anyone could help?

Comment: $d\mu_1=g(x)d\mu_2$ for some $g\geq1$, give many other examples.

Comment: For any subset $A$, $\mu_2(A)\leq \mu_1(A)$

Comment: It suffices that $\mu_2(A)\le \mu_1(A)$ for any interval  $A$.